# Angular ngbTypeahead filter of list

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngb-typeahead

I've got a ngbTypeahead which when typing in the field should be able to get a list of strings.

```
            <ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
              <a>
                      <span class="ml-1">
                        <ngb-highlight [result]="r" [term]="t"></ngb-highlight>
                      </span>
              </a>
            </ng-template>
            <div class="form-group row mb-1">
              <label for="libelle" class="col-md-3 text-right pr-0">Employeur</label>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <input class="form-control ml-1" id="libelle" name="libelle"
                       [(ngModel)]="libelle"
                       placeholder="Employeur"
                       [ngbTypeahead]="search"
                       (selectItem)="selectItemLibelle($event)"
                       [inputFormatter]="formatMatches" [resultTemplate]="rt"
                       (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
                       >
              </div>
            </div>
```

the typscript code :

```
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged() );
    const  inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

    return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$).pipe(
      mergeMap((term) => {
        return this.getEmp(term).pipe(map((emp: any) => {
          return ((!term || false || term === '') ? emp
            : emp.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1));
        }));
      })
    );
  }

  selectItemLibelle($event) {
    this.libelle = $event.item;
    $event.preventDefault();
  }

  formatMatches = (value: any) => value || '';
```

the method getEmp, get the list of strings :

```
  getEmp(term): Observable<any[]> {
  this.fe2ModeleService.getEmployeurs(term).subscribe((employeurs) => {this.listEmp = employeurs;});
  return of(this.listEmp);}
```

everything works fine, when I search with a character or a phrase I get the list , my issue is I want when I click on the input (when the input is empty) I want to have the complete list.

the problem is when I come the first time in the page or I refresh the page, and I click on the input nothing is displayed, but when I click elsewhere (on another input or on anywhere on the page) and I come back and click on the input, and there I have the list displayed.
how can I have this behavior from the first time I come to the page

get the complete list when I click on the input

Answer (score 1):

I used `combineLatest` instead of `mergeMap`:

```
  search: OperatorFunction<string, readonly PostCategory[]> = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));

    const operations$ = merge(debouncedText$, clicksWithClosedPopup$, this.focus$, this.clear$);

    return combineLatest([
      operations$,
      this.categories$
    ]).pipe(
      map(([text, categories]) =>
        text === '' ? categories : categories.filter(c => new RegExp(`^${text}`, 'i').test(c.name)))
    );
  }
```

You can find the working code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-posts

Comment: Thanks for your response, I used the combineLatest, but I still have another issue,
in fact my ngTypeahead have two list,, when the user click automaticly a list from api get display, but while typing if the input match o certain regex I made another call api to get another list,
this the code I made so far, but still dont work, I get the first list but not the second

Comment: ****
return combineLatest([
      operations$, this.newListEmp ]).pipe(
      map(([term, emp]) => {
        if (this.regex_bcr.test(term)) {
          this.newListEmpBcr = [];
          this.sl4ClientService.findByBCR(term).subscribe(client => this.newListEmpBcr.push(client));
        }
        return term === '' ? emp : this.newListEmpBcr.length === 0 ?
          emp.filter((v) => v.designation.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1) :
          this.newListEmpBcr.filter((v) => v.designation.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1); }));}